# Asignar un GameObject al script de un prefab

Tags: c#, script, unity3d

Estoy haciendo el proyecto final de mi curso de desarrollo de videojuegos, el cual se trata de un Space Invaders. Resulta que tengo casi todo listo, y una de las cosas que me faltaría es la puntuación. Tengo creado un manager de puntuación con el script (el cual se encuentra en la escena), el cual debería sumar los puntos una vez que el láser «instanciado» choque contra los enemigos.

El problema es que, al ser el láser un prefab, no puedo asignar dicho mánager de puntos al script.

A continuación os dejo el código, tanto de la nave del jugador, el láser y el mánager de puntos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código de la nave del jugador:**

```
public class MovimientoJugador : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Movimiento
    private float ejeHorizontal = 0f;
    public float velocidadHorizontal = 1f; //Horizontal Speed
    public float posicionMinimaX = -6f; //Minimum position
    public float posicionMaximaX = 6f; //Maximum position


    //Disparo
    public GameObject disparo; //Shot Prefab
    public Transform disparoPos; //Shot start position

    void Update()
    {
        //Movimiento
        ejeHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if (ejeHorizontal != 0f)
        {
            Vector3 nuevaPosicion = transform.position;
            nuevaPosicion.x = nuevaPosicion.x + (velocidadHorizontal * ejeHorizontal * Time.deltaTime);
            nuevaPosicion.x = Mathf.Clamp(nuevaPosicion.x, posicionMinimaX, posicionMaximaX);
            transform.position = nuevaPosicion;

        }

        //Disparo
        if (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Disparo").Length <1) //Only 1 shot
        {
            if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
            {

            Instantiate(disparo, disparoPos.position, disparoPos.rotation);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Código del mánager de puntos:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ManagerPuntos : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int puntuacion = 0;
    public Text textoPuntuacion;
    public void SumarPuntos(int puntosASumar)
    {
        puntuacion = puntuacion + puntosASumar;
        Debug.Log("+" + puntosASumar + "\nPuntación: " + puntuacion);
        textoPuntuacion.text = puntuacion.ToString();
    }

    public GameObject objetoMenu;
    public GameObject textoVictoria;

    public void Victoria()
    {
        textoVictoria.SetActive(true);
        objetoMenu.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

**Código del láser:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Misil : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float velocidad; //speed
    private Rigidbody2D rig;
    public ManagerPuntos managerPuntos; //Point Manager

    void Awake()
    {
        rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        rig.velocity = transform.up * velocidad;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemigo")) //Compare to "Enemy" tag
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Como consejo, si quieres ayuda muy especifica en unity, deberías valorar visitar [GameDev StackExchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: GameObject.Find() no te funciona?

Comment: @PacManProgramador Pues lo he intentado, pero no sé si es porque lo estoy poniendo mal o algo, pero no se me asigna como tal.
«GameObject.Find("Puntos")»

Comment: Prueba con un debug.log a ese objeto, si no te devuelvo nulo, esta bien, y el problema esta en otro lado

Comment: Hola Amigo lo pudiste solucionar? yo tengo el mismo problema y he detectado que los prefabs no reciben cierto tipo de objetos o scripts por que no están en la hierarchy cuando arrastras el prefab a este campo se convierte en un objeto y si si recibe scripts y objetos pero el prefab no y no se modifica. si lo resolviste agradecería que lo comentaras para que pueda servir de ayuda a otros con ese problema. un saludo.

Comment: @Mommos, sí conseguí solucionarlo. Dejé la misma pregunta en los fotos de Unity 3D y me ayudaron. Te dejó el link para que le eches un vistazo. :) https://answers.unity.com/questions/1737710/assing-a-gameobject-to-a-prefabs-script.html?childToView=1738387#comment-1738387

Answer (score 0):

Agrega un TAG a tu manager de puntos, y luego agrega esto:

```
nombre = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("tuTAG").GetComponent<SCRIPT>();
```

No te recomiendo que uses Find(); ya que todo depende del nombre y te puedes equivocar facilmente.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor revisa [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer); para que tu respuesta tenga mas contexto y ayude al usuario